# RewriteRule is not working with plus (+ or *) character

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]).php$  /index.php?zig=$1 [NC,L] # working
```

This rule is working correctly. But

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+).php$  /index.php?zig=$1 [NC,L] # not working
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]\+).php$  /index.php?zig=$1 [NC,L] # not working
```

Is not working. Difference is (`+`). How to use `+` in the code above?

Comment: Top tip: the phrase "not working" is to be avoided in problem descriptions. It's too vague. Instead, describe precisely what happens (with evidence!) and explain how it differs from what you wanted to happen instead. We cannot divine what you want to achieve from code that, by your own admission, _does not achieve that thing_! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This rule is fine:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\.php$  /index.php?zig=$1 [NC,L]
```

but will create an infinite loop since rewritten URI `/index.php` also matches the regex pattern. To prevent this you need couple of changes like preventing files/directories from this rewrite and escape the dot as it is a special regex meta character:

```
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\.php$ index.php?zig=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

`QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.